# Getting error on configuring Search Navigation while provisioning site

Tags: 2013, search, navigation

I have a requirement of configuring Search Navigation setting while Provisioning the site Collection.

Working fine in my local solution when I'm directly passing site collection to configure search settings.

But getting error if i configure along when i provision the site collection.

Getting the below error

> | ERROR | Error occurred during
>   ProvisionLibrary.ProvisionSiteCollection.ProvisioningSearchScope:
>   Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object
>   returned by the following call stack is null. "GetNodeById Navigation
>   "    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream
>   responseStream)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()    at
>   ProvisionLibrary.ProvisionSiteCollection.ProvisioningSearchScope()

Here is my code

```
        try
        {
            Log.Trace("Starting Search Scope Provisioning");
            ClientContext oclientContext = new ClientContext(Context.Site.Url);                
            Web oweb = oclientContext.Web;
            oclientContext.Load(oweb);
            //oclientContext.Load(oweb.Navigation.GetNodeById(1040));
            oclientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Log.Trace("Before Fetching Node"+ oweb.Url);
            NavigationNode searchNavRoot = oweb.Navigation.GetNodeById(1040);
            oclientContext.Load(searchNavRoot, root => root.Children);
            oclientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Log.Trace("After Fetching Node" + oweb.Url);
            // Get the navigation node collection.
            //oclientContext.Load(searchNavRoot, root => root.Children);

            Log.Trace("Before Fetching Children" + oweb.Url);

            NavigationNodeCollection collNavigationNode = searchNavRoot.Children;

            Log.Trace("After Fetching Children" + oweb.Url);

            // Set properties for a new navigation node.
            NavigationNodeCreationInformation ciNavicationNode = new NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
            //SearchScopeList searchScope = new SearchScopeList();
            //Log.Trace("Before loading scope" + Context.Site.Url);
            //IList<SearchScopeList> SearchScopeColl = searchScope.LoadSearchScope(Context.Site.Url);

            Log.Trace("Before Load external: " + oweb.Url);
            ciNavicationNode.IsExternal = true;
            ciNavicationNode.Title = "Test";
            ciNavicationNode.Url = "Http://www.google.com";
            collNavigationNode.Add(ciNavicationNode);
            oclientContext.Load(collNavigationNode);
            oclientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use the below code and check the result :

```
          using (ClientContext Context = new ClientContext("Site URL"))
        {
            SecureString password = CreateSecurePassword("password");
            Context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", password);                
            Web oWeb = Context.Web;

            Context.Load(oWeb);
            //oclientContext.Load(oweb.Navigation.GetNodeById(1040));
            Context.ExecuteQuery();

            NavigationNodeCollection searchNavRoot = oWeb.Navigation.GetNodeById(1040).Children;
            Context.Load(searchNavRoot);
            Context.ExecuteQuery();
            // Get the navigation node collection.
            //oclientContext.Load(searchNavRoot, root => root.Children)


            // Set properties for a new navigation node.
            NavigationNodeCreationInformation searchNav = new NavigationNodeCreationInformation();

            searchNav.IsExternal = true;
            searchNav.Title = "Test";
            searchNav.Url = "Http://www.google.com";
            searchNavRoot.Add(searchNav);
            Context.Load(searchNavRoot);
            Context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

I hope this helps. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as answer if this resolves your issue.

Comment: I tried this also getting the same error, This code works fine if i'm running from my local project. If I configure the Search Navigation settings while provisioning the site collection then this is  error Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. "GetNodeById
Navigation
"
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()

Comment: How are you applying these changes, While provisioning is in process or after provisioning of site is completed ?. In First scenario, it will not be able to create the object of site and In second scenario, I will suggest to wait for 10 minutes before proceeding with these changes. If possible please give the complete code for a better understanding.